# .net obfuscate problem

Tags: .net, assemblies, obfuscation

I receive an unhandled exception error like  "Could not load file or assembly ‘abc, Version=....., Culture=neutral, PublicKey Token=null’ or one of its dependences."... something similar to this guys problem [here](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/256149-microsoftnet-framework-unhandled-exception/).

Scenario 1:
.Net 3.5. - abc.dll used by def.exe - abc.dll is obfuscated by VS 2008's Dotfuscator CE - works fine.

Scenario 2:
upgraded to .Net 4.0 - abc.dll used by def.exe - abc.dll obfuscated by VS 2010's Dotfuscator CE- gives the above error but when continued works fine.. gives the same error while closing the application.

Scenario 2 works fine if not obfuscated.

Could you tell me what that error means and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning on assembly binding logging to check what assemblies are probed and where is the name difference that you seem to be experiencing.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) question for details how to do that.